# Migrate solution with mulitple .NET projects to .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, upgrade

I have a simple console project with one dependency that is a library project. Both are targetting .NET 4.8.

The second project is a project reference in the console project.

[image]

I want to migrate both projects to .NET Core. For doing that is use the Visual Studio extension ".NET Upgrade Assistant".

I right clicked on the console project and selected "Upgrade". In the following menu, I choose "Upgrade to a newer .NET version", after that "In-place project upgrade" and then ".NET 7."

[image]

I was under the impression that the referenced project would also be upgraded. But that was not the case.

Is there a way to have it also upgraded?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that .NET to .NET Core would technically be a downgrade. .NET 4.8 is really .NET _Framework_ 4.8 and .NET 7 is not .NET _Core_. you really mean ".NET Framework to .NET". Yes... I know the naming is confusing but it is what it is 

Comment: You will have to "upgrade" the MigrationTestBackend project separately but you might be able to get away with just changing the target of that to .NET Standard 2.0 depending upon it's dependencies.